# Name of book for Photographers and Graphic designers to advertise in the 80's and 90's?

Tags: photography-basics

I am looking for a industry agency book (I think a new one comes out once a year) that has pretty much gone out of business.

It's a thick smaller book that Photographers / Graphic Design Firms would advertise in. It was about $10,000 for a full page ad. I remember is was heavily used in the 80’s and 90’s but has pretty much died out because of the internet.

Does anyone remember what these books were called?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably thinking of [Photographer's Market](https://books.google.com/books?id=2iSHLf4zOFUC&q=photographer%27s+market&dq=photographer%27s+market&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqtdT6mOThAhXsmeAKHRESDBQQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg). I remember seeing it in the library when looking through photography magazines in the 1990s.

It was published by Writer's Digest, and later F&W Media. It seems to still be A Thing, as the [2018 version is available on Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/Photographers-Market-2018-Noel-Rivera/dp/1440352534) — it says "41st edition".